# Get partial class name and text inside div using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, domparser

I need to get two values from this HTML, which is either  an error or a success from `toast-*`, and also get the value inside the `toast-message`:

```
<div class="toast toast-error" style="">
    <div class="toast-message">You have failed.</div> 
</div>
<div class="toast toast-success" style="">
    <div class="toast-message">You have succeed. 
</div>
```

The `div` elements only show once at a single time, which can be either error or success.

Is there any way I can use regex, so I can extract the value within array so it either:

```
['success', 'You have succeed.']
```

or

```
['error', 'You have failed.']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression here? Do you have a reference to the elements?

Comment: @CertainPerformance because that div in string format and not original html file

Comment: @bakaio And are you unable to parse the string as HTML? At with the other 1000 times per day that a "how do I parse HTML with regex" question appears on StackOverflow, I'll post the obligatory: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Comment: The "right" way to parse HTML is by using an HTML parser. Not a regex. For example, with [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri). Is there definitely a good reason for you to use regex?

Comment: If you control the HTML generation and can guarantee that it will be of the *exact* same format every time -- same attribute order, same whitespace, no variation in the node structure, etc -- then you *might* be able to get away with doing this in regex.  

Of course, if you can guarantee that, then you probably don't need regex, because you could extract the data from whatever upstream process is generating the HTML in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the elements.

```js
let parser = new DOMParser();
let html = `<div class="toast toast-error" style=""><div class="toast-message">You have failed.</div></div>`;
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
let div = doc.querySelector("div.toast");
let successOrFailure = div.getAttribute('class')
  .split(" ")
  .filter(word => word.substring(0, 6) === "toast-")[0]
  .substring(6);
let message = div.firstChild.innerHTML;
let result = [successOrFailure, message];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, I replace domparser with jsdom since its running on node.

Answer (score 1):

A preferred way would be to use the source strings and, **with the help of the DOM**, test, whether the element is present:

```js
const html1 = `
  <div class="toast toast-error" style="">
    <div class="toast-message">You have failed.</div>
  </div>  
`;

const html2 = `
  <div class="toast toast-success" style="">
    <div class="toast-message">You have succeed.</div>
  </div>
`;

/**
 * Returns the text of the error toast message.
 *
 * @returns {string|null} The toast message, or null if the elemenet is not present.
 */
function getErrorToastText(string) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = string;

  const toast = container.querySelector('.toast-error .toast-message');
  return toast ? toast.innerHTML : null;
}

/**
 * Returns the text of the success toast message.
 *
 * @returns {string|null} The toast message, or null if the elemenet is not present.
 */
function getSuccessToastText(string) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = string;

  const toast = container.querySelector('.toast-success .toast-message');
  return toast ? toast.innerHTML : null;
}


console.log('when .error-toast element present:', getErrorToastText(html1));
console.log('when .error-toast element not present:', getErrorToastText(html2));

console.log('when .success-toast element present:', getSuccessToastText(html2));
console.log('when .success-toast element not present:', getSuccessToastText(html1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. I only listed three of them, to see all of them [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/5559423)

**1. Using (ES6) JS function `includes`**

```
var str = "toast toast-success",
    substr = "success";
str.includes(substr);
```

**2. Using `indexOf`**

```
var str = "toast toast-success",
    substr = "success";
if(str.indexOf(substr) == 1){
    // the current div is a success
    // do your logic
}
```

**3. Using Regex**

```
// you get this string by getting class-list of the div
var str= "toast toast-success",         
    substr= /-success$/;   // or /-error$/
string.match(expr);
```